# Grammar improvement in a sentence

Tags: grammar

My teacher gave me a worksheet today.

I found a sentence saying:

> The main character and the novelist, who serves as the narrator, share a vital experience.

This I found confusing, because the way I would say what the sentence is intended to say is:

> The main character, also the novelist, who serves as the narrator, shares a vital experience.

Or I would just change *serves* to *serve*.

But my teacher insisted on saying that there is nothing wrong with the sentence's grammar.

**WHY?**

Comment: Your teacher is correct; there's nothing wrong with the grammar. You have misinterpreted the meaning. The clause _`P₁` and `P₂` share `X`_ requires that `P₁` and `P₂` be two distinct people. Or, as in this case, two different characters in a narrative. Note that _the_ is repeated in _the main character and the novelist_, instead of undergoing conjunction reduction to _the main character and novelist_, which would imply they were the same person.

Comment: They are **not** the same person in the first part, at least if the transcript is correct. They are different all through. The main character shares an experience with the novelist, who serves as the narrator. As I said, you have misinterpreted the meaning.

Comment: The sentence speaks of two people: let's call them A and B. A is the main character. B is the novelist. The story is narrated by B, so B serves as the narrator. A does not serve as the narrator. A and B share a vital experience.

Comment: If parentheses will help, here: (The main character and (the novelist, who serves as the narrator)) share a vital experience.

Comment: No but the repeated the implies that they are the same person. As Lawler said. Yet I kinda understand now

Comment: Prof. Lawler said quite the opposite :)

Comment: So, John, you think "The main character and the novelist, who are one and the same, necessarily share experiences" would be ungrammatical?

Comment: @Doeser No, he said that if conjunction reduction had applied, you would have had “The main character and novelist”, which would have implied that it was just one person. But conjunction reduction has _not_ applied, and it is not “The main character and novelist”. The repeated _the_ strongly implies that they are two **different** people.

Comment: Yes, I agree there is nothing wrong with the sentence's grammar .Your teacher is correct . If you have any doubt, then to check your sentence in Nounplus . It gives you accurate results . I always use it .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main idea of this sentence is "The main character and the novelist share a vital experience."  It is not implied that they are the same person --in fact, given that the word *share* requires two subjects, they cannot be.

Into this main idea the clause "who serves as the narrator" is inserted, basically as a parenthetical further describing the novelist.

If, instead, it were "The main character (and the novelist) is the narrator," the meaning would be closer to how you have interpreted it, but in that case "The novelist is the main character and the narrator" would be much more clear.

Comment: Then why is the repeated ?

Comment: I don't think the repeated "the" serves the function you think it does --it's not clear to me why you think it argues against this interpretation.

Comment: @Doeser, the repeated *the* implies (but does not determine) that *the main character* and *the novelist* are **unique individuals**. It seems you misread John Lawler's comment: **conjunction reduction to *the main character and novelist* ... would imply they were the same person**. You repeated the mistake you made with your teacher's sentence: a relative clause generally modifies the **closest reasonable referent**. In your post: *Who?* **The novelist!** In John Lawler's comment: *Which?* **Conjunction reduction to *the main character and novelist*!**